# Reactjs Fetch Data by express get Cors Policy Error

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I have a api that fetch data from a Mysql database

```
export const getProducts = (req, res) => {
const q = "SELECT * FROM product"

db.query(q,(err,data)=>{
    if(err) return res.json(err);
    return res.json(data);
})
};
```

There are 586 rows and 244.6MiB for the 'product' table.

The problem is it take long time to fetch all the data from the database, then this error "origin 'xxxxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" occur.

There are no cors policy error for INSERT , UPDATE AND DELETE api, only GET api occur cors policy error.

Is there any solution to solve this?